# In the pkcs11interop project code, I see CKM_ECDSA_SHA256, but in the nuget package I added to my solution its not there

Tags: c#, sha256, pkcs#11, ecdsa, pkcs11interop

I need to use ECDSA with sha256 with a hsm and I am using c# with the http://www.pkcs11interop.net/ wrapper. The Github code has CKM_ECDSA_SHA256, but not the 3.3.0 release even though the release is the latest as of Jan 24 and the enum was added much earlier.

Why cannot I access the enum? I could use CKM_ECDSA and hash before signing, but that would defeat the purpose of using the hsm for its speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CKM_ECDSA_SHA256 enum member was added on 1 March 2017 as a part of [larger patch](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/Pkcs11Interop/commit/1d442cae3a1470cdc28c0df806c628d36d59007d) that added support for PKCS#11 v2.40. It was not present in Pkcs11Interop v3.3.0 but it is present in [master branch](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/Pkcs11Interop/blob/master/src/Pkcs11Interop/Pkcs11Interop/Common/CKM.cs#L1352) on GitHub which is yet to be released as Pkcs11Interop v4.0.0.

Meanwhile you can use overloaded method which accepts ulong instead of CKM and define missing constant in your code:

```
const ulong CKM_ECDSA_SHA256 = 0x00001044;
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try that!